# chef remote_file is throwing Encoding::UndefinedConversionError

Tags: ruby, chef, chef-solo, ubuntu-14.04

I have the following in a chef recipe:

```
remote_file '/tmp/zint-2.4.2.zip' do
  source 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket/zint-2.4.2.zip'
  checksum '4dc28641ef79957e9d3f0904a5d56472ef1d66f8529e3deda25537d890a6f8f3'
  mode '0664'
  action :create_if_missing
end
```

On Ubuntu 14.04 with ruby1.9.1 this is throwing "Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: "\xA2" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8" when I run chef-solo on boot.  If I run chef-solo manually after start up, the cookbook completes successfully.

This seems related to https://github.com/yevgenko/cookbook-php-fpm/issues/36 as I added the following code to my php5-fpm recipe:

```
if RUBY_VERSION =~ /1.9/
  Encoding.default_external = Encoding::UTF_8
  Encoding.default_internal = Encoding::UTF_8
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be this bug:  https://tickets.opscode.com/browse/CHEF-4746  I'm going to downgrade to chef-solo 11.4

Comment: THis worked on an EC2 instance, but running this on a vagrant instance (same ruby, same chef version, same OS) did not work and it failed.